# Pandas raising an error when setting the output directory

Tags: python, pandas

There is OSError when I try to set the output directory and write Prefix in front of `"i"` such as `'cal_'` or `'edit_'`. If I added the postfix like `df.to_csv(i + '_edit.csv')`, the result was `"filename.csv_edit"`. 
So the files were saved the input directory and I couldn't add any prefix and postfix. How to fix this error?

```
import pandas as pd
import glob    

PathIn = r'C:\Users\input'
PathOut = r'C:\Users\output'
filenames = glob.glob(PathIn + "/*.csv")

file_list = []
for i in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(i)
    file_list.append(df)

    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('[','')
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(']','')

    df.to_csv(i + '.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. This should work. It has the full code you want.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

PathIn = r'C:\Users\input'
PathOut = r'C:\Users\output'

file_list = []
for name in os.listdir(PathIn):
    if name.endswith(".csv"):
        #print(name)
        df = pd.read_csv(PathIn + "\" + name)
        file_list.append(df)

        df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('[','')
        df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(']','')

        df.to_csv(PathOut + name)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is the same error that is **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File (file name.csv) does not exist.** when I ran `print(df)` to test `df = pd.read_csv(name)`. I think it would need the all path when we use `pd.read_csv()`.

Comment: yes correct. While reading you need to provide the full path. My bad. Updated answer

Comment: Oh, I see. The full path was the key. You've really helped me out, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The value of `i` in filenames is the absolute path of the csv file you are reading.

So if you have 3 csv files in your input directory, you filenames list will be like below :

`['C:\Users\input\file1.csv',
 'C:\Users\input\file2.csv',
 'C:\Users\input\file3.csv']`

Now you are trying to add a prefix in front of the elements of above list which would not be a valid `path`.

You need to fetch the filename of input file and append it with `PathOut` so that a valid path exists.

You can fetch the filenames in any directory as below :

```
filenames = []
for entry in os.listdir(PathIn):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(PathIn, entry)) and ".csv" in entry:
        filenames.append(entry)
```

Now you can iterate over this list and do operations you were doing. For saving the final `df` to file in output directory, append the filenames with `PathOut`.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include fetching of filenames in a directory. Have a look. Also you can find a lot of other different ways to list files in a directory.